# Can I force Flash games to play in fullscreen mode?

Tags: flash

I download Flash games from several sites and some of them can be played on fullscreen and some cannot be. How can I change the screen size of the game to accomodate my screen? Is there a way to force all Flash games to be played in fullscreen mode?

Comment: what game? are you playing in a browser? if a game doesn't offer a full-screen option itself, there's not much you can do (that would be in the scope of this site)

Comment: We can't answer how to edit a flash file. That would fall under http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ . We could try to help you resize your windows on flash games that don't allow for resizeability, but if it requires coding or changing the flash file, generally any coding or game editing should go to the GameDev stack exchange.

Comment: @TZHX: I am playing in a browser but the game is downloaded that is I am not playing it through some website. So my question is that how can I change the size of the game? The game is made to stretch when there is a higher resolution than 720x576p. So if my resolution is 1920x1080 the game stretches itself but the game stretches itself in it's aspect ratio i.e. in a multiple of 720x576. So how can I change this behavior and let it stretch without aspect ratio. Also if I change my resolution to 720x576 the game runs good in fullscreen. I want to play it in 1920x1080 mode.

Comment: Well the normal fix is to change the res of monitor to that of the game, then it opens up correctly. Also decompiling and all won't work as then I'll just have to make them and start editing all the pics and everything. Naw I'll just leave it as they are. And thanks aal you guys.

Answer (score 4):

If you play in a browser, you culd use a bookmarklet or user script to full screen the game element. 
Try pasting something like this in your address bar:

```
javascript: addEventListener('click', function(ev) {var el = ev.target, rfs = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen || el.mozRequestFullScreen; rfs.call(el);});
```

This should fullscreen a clicked element.
In some browsers (*cough* Chrome *cough*), you'll need to type the "javascript:" part yourself. Put it in a bookmark to circumvent that.

Comment: This works for some browser games, need to click on the element surrounding the flash game not the game itself.  Nice one, exactly what I needed so my small child will be able to play the game without accidentally scrolling, clicking something else, etc.  In Chrome at least, we can also zoom the game to make it larger in the normal way.

Comment: @SamWatkins Zooming in? OF COURSE! I didn't though in this simple approach. My baby wants to play too haha. She's 1 year old! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Normally, a Flash object stretches to fill all space given to it in the `<object>` or `<embed>` container, stand alone Flash player window, or screen. If it doesn't, there's nothing you can do without access to the original .fla file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing in Browser, use this script;
https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/4870-maximize-video

Answer (score 1):

Back when I played lots of Flash games, many implemented a protection in form of an exact window/frame size specification to prevent/discourage hotlinking for example.

Code like that for example would be a big problem for your plan.

I.e. the game would actually display a piracy warning if played at an incorrect resolution. Some would actually go as far as not doing anything besides displaying said warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do so natively, but that doesn't [stop you from decompiling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=flash+decompiler) to get .fla files from which you can further modify.

Be aware most flash decompilers are complete dirt, so it takes quite a bit of effort to do anything useful. Even then, a given flash file is very unreadable and usually you'll end up having to build it back up from scratch using the various pieces.

All in all, it's pretty difficult to do and only somewhat legal.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

1. Right-click taskbar > Taskbar settings > Turn on the "Automatically hide" option;
2. Download WinExplorer: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winexp.html;
3. Launch the Flash game as you would normally;
4. Run the winexp.exe as Administrator;
5. Click on the Style tab; Uncheck all styles except WS_VISIBLE (WS_CLIPSIBLINGS seems to want to stay checked for me too);
6. Click on the Size & Position tab; In the General section, type in Left: 0, Top: 0, Width:(fill in your current screen width divided by any scaling applied - for example, for me it's 2160/1.5), Height:(fill in using current screen height divided by any scaling);
7. Click Modify button;
8. Close the WinExplorer;
9. Go back to the game window (Alt-Tab, etc.);

The game window should be full screen now. If you right-click desktop > Display settings, you can view your screen size and scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> on some keyboards) will fullscreen the `HTML` element, therefore making the entire game fullscreen.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, so please try this.

Right click on the shortcut of the flash game that you wish to play full screen and then click properties. Once the properties window is open, make sure the "shortcut" tab is selected and then look for the word "Run" and then click on the drop down menu beside it and change it from "Normal" to "Maximized". Then click apply and then ok.

After that, whenever you open that game, it should automatically open maximized. Just make sure though that you always open it using that shortcut. If there is no shortcut and just only the main .exe for that game, you will need to create a shortcut first, and then after you do that, just follow the same steps that I mentioned above.

I hope this helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

There are games that allow you to open in full screen, there are games created by the developer that it doesn't respond so when you open the whole screen it doesn't grow.